# TRIM on non-SSD RAID?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, trim

A server has been experiencing temporary lockups (1-8 minutes) for some time and I recently found they have been corresponding to VSS snapshots lately.  Through event logs I was able to determine that TRIM is enabled on the server (disabledeletenotify = 0).

The system will typically become unresponsive for a short period of time and then recover.

There are no SSD's installed.  The server has a Dell PERC H200 RAID adapter with 4 Seagate ST3300657SS-H 15k SAS drives connected.

*** Is there *any* reason TRIM should have been enabled in this case? ***

I've disabled TRIM for now since I don't know if it was necessary, but this may not be the reason the system was locking up.

We have hourly incremental backups running using ShadowProtect.

Here are some events around when things go wrong and then when it recovers:

---

10:00 AM

Source: stcvsc  Event ID: 6

Snapshot created for volume on \Device\HarddiskVolume3.

---

10:08 AM (around when the system comes online)

Source: stcvsm  Event ID: 15

TRIM/UNMAP request on \Device\HarddiskVolume3 ignored since it attempted to touch the snapshot storage.

---

10:09 AM

Source: stcvsm  Event ID: 265

VDIFF reset occured on \Device\HarddiskVolume3. The data is the new reset count.

---

10:09 AM

Source: stcvsm  Event ID 7

Snapshot deleted for volume on \Device\HarddiskVolume4.

Comment: That TRIM command is probably NOT what's slowing you down. It's more likely going to be something to do with the OS creating the VSS.  If you manually create a VSS does it lock in the same way? You're not running Symantec Endpoint Protection by any chance are you?

Comment: Basically, do you want an answer about Trim being ienabled, or do you want help solving your actual problem? If it's the later, please edit and reword you question to be about the actual problem, and not about what you suspect is the cause ([XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)). If it's the former, then delete all the other stuff that's unrelated to the actual question about Trim.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Hi, not running Symantec Endpoint but that servers is running ESET File Security for Servers 4.5  And thanks for the comment, I was basically looking to see if there was any reason TRIM may be enabled rather than a solution to the actual issue.  I realized after the other events TRIM probably had little to do with the lockups.